# Recursive Enumeration of Sites, Subsites, and Application Templates Used

Tags: site-collection, site-template, stsadm

I am migrating my WSS 3.0 installation over to 2010 and then eventually to 2013 and am in need of a stsadm command that will show me a list of sites in the site collection, a list of subsites within that site, and the Application Template in which the site was created as.

I was able to use the following to get my site collection list:

```
stsadm -o enumsites -url http://mysharepointsite.local/
```

Then, I was able to get a list of sub sites for an individual site:

```
stsadm -o enumsubwebs -url http://mysharepointsite.local/sites/SomeSubWeb/
```

BUT, I would like a recursive method of doing this as we have 100's of sites with subsites in one call possibly or even a map in the Central Administration.  I also need to know which Application Template was used to create the site as I am trying to find 2010 equivalents to the templates and found them but need to know which site uses which template and SharePoint knows somehow since I get a list of the Application Templates that are used during the pre-upgrade checker.

I was using a [TechNet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2008/03/15/complete-reference-of-all-stsadm-operations-with-parameters-in-moss-2007-sp1.aspx) list of all stsadm functions as a reference and cannot figure out which one to use to get what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across the enumallwebs operation and that seems to do the trick.  For anyone looking, this command will give you the Sites in the collection and any sub webs contained in each and is completely recursive.  It also lets you know the URL, LanguageID, TemplateName, TemplateID, and OwnerLogin.  EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Here is the link to the [Library Reference for Enumallwebs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793606%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Below is an example of usage:

```
stsadm -o enumallwebs -databasename "MYSPCONTENTDBNAME"
```

Hope this helps someone looking...

Comment: The prob with enumallwebs is that it requires sp2 .... :-(

Comment: Thanks for the information. I haven't had to work with 2007 in years. This helped a lot and got me the data I needed.